# Is node.js ready for medium/big business web application?

Tags: node.js, symfony, express

I work on studying the development of a medium web application intended for hotlines. So I've real time, concurent access, big datamodel and CTI constraints.

Originaly I'm a php and Java EE developper, but like many of us, I've read a lot of news about node.js and I tested it with small apps. The possibilities of node.js are awesome, but I felt that it's very difficult to only use this technology in a medium/big web app. Indeed frameworks like express are minimalistic compared to productive framework like symfony, play or ROR, etc. Moreover, the node.js ecosystem progresses very fast and might be difficult to maintain.

I'm not experienced enough in nodejs, so I want to know; is choosing only node.js to develop a medium/big business web app with some real time problematics crazy or not? Don't you think that coupling a productive framework with nodejs only for specific features (real time) is a better way ?

Thanks,
Regards
Eric

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a large real-time business web app that requires some real-time interaction and what we are doing is using django for just about everything, and handling the real-time stuff using the now.js library. Originally we planned on using node.js for everything, but to alleviate some time constraints, we decided it would be quicker to use django.

One thing we have noticed since we've started is that there are a lot of changes, and that some of these changes break what we've done. For the most part, keeping up with the changes hasn't really made it difficult to maintain, however it has made it difficult to follow tutorials and such.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer this quickly, before the question is closed for only being answerable via opinions, not facts.

So, I'm going to answer with my opinion ;)

I think node.js's focus currently is on building small things that respond very quickly. I sense a lot of pushback in the node community against "too complicated abstractions". (It's possible I'm misreading the community, but I don't think so).

To me, building a business app (example: some of my past Rails projects have been 10ish man years) I *want* an ORM abstraction layer, etc. I think you'd want this building even an app with more than a few man-months of effort in it.

Unless something changes (the node community runs into problems when their code bases grow too large, for example) I suspect the "place" for node.js in medium to big applications is for small hyper responsive things (websockets, retrieving data from external sources and doing small things with it), etc.... not for building an entire big business workflow app.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2016. Recently I decided to go with Sails / Node instead of CakePHP. Today I decided to go back to CakePHP. Lucky enough, I just coded one small module ( kinda of indexing inside a db some filesystem content ). The amount of callbacks and promises It's just annoying to me. The simple task of getting a file's metadata, searching it on Postgres, creating the record only if it doesn't exists, take me more than 20 lines of code and I almost have to drink a bottle of Dramamine lol

This time I am highly determinated to maintain an extreme layer's separation. So my front-end is fully static html/js/css, coded in Angular. Postgres DB also don't require any changes. And CakePHP 3 is almost factory's ready to easily serve json/xml.

Also there's a possibility of me being somehow stupid... lol